# PHP Framework Deployment on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Almost all the new PHP frameworks require Composer for installation, but my question is that if I develop an application with such a framework locally, can it be deployed to a shared web hosting, without access to ssh or Composer?

Comment: It can be installed, but it will be painful especially for a newbie. You'll meet a lot of difficulties and constraints. So I'd really recommend you to add a buck and use VPS or cloud.

Comment: Yes, just copy up all the files from local->host like you would with any other web site directory structure

Comment: or just ask the service provider if they support composer based installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy to shared hosting, but you'll need to avoid using composer ( to install in production ). I would suggest just using composer locally and the using FTP to upload the entire project, as you would a normal project.